# AngularJS + Parse API call service not constrained by userId as intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, parse-platform

For my app, I've created a service for *Address*, which allows me to manipulate Address objects for any given user. Aside from my standard CRUD functions, I need to have one function to list any address for a specified Parse.User.

**services.js**

```
.factory('Address',['$http', 'PARSE_CREDENTIALS', function ($http,PARSE_CREDENTIALS) {
    return {
        // constrain to User ID
        getAll: function(userId) {
            return $http.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Address', {
                headers: {
                    'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
                    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                params: { "userId": userId }
            });
        },
        // ...get(), edit(), add(), delete()
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('AddrCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$rootScope', 'Address',
function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope, Address) {
        Address.getAll($rootScope.user.id)
        .success( function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.addresses = data.results;
        })
}]);
```

In my Angular template, the view does return Address objects. But it returns *all* the Address objects when it should only be returning the Address objects with a corresponding userId. To clarify, the Address class has a userId pointer column. Each address only has one User.

Here is the log message that `AddrCtrl` returns in the console:

```
Object {results: Array[2]}
    results: Array[2]
        0: Object
            firstName: "(test)"
            lastName: "test"
            // more unrelated properties
            objectId: "yUEuFjLlzs"
            updatedAt: "2014-12-02T20:17:55.608Z"
            userId: Object
                __type: "Pointer"
                className: "_User"
                objectId: "q1KADkp4i1"
```

I'm assuming that the issue lies somewhere in my $http.get() function. Ultimately, my questions is this: why does my `params` option not constrain my `data.results` to just the Address objects associated with one Parse.User?

**Answer I am not looking for:**

> Return all Address objects and only save the ones matching Parse.User.current().id into $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `where` clause to perform the query.

If the data type of `userId` is `Pointer`, you should write as following:

```
{"where": JSON.stringify({
    "userId": {"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"userId"}}
)}
```